# Applications of Lefschetz formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-topology

Could you tell me anything about applications of Lefschetz formula:

$$\Lambda(f, X)=\sum_{f(x)=x} i(x).$$

I found out in Fomenko, Fuchs "Homotopic topology" that it implies Shub-Sullivan conjecture: mapping of torus, homotopic to one induced by matrix without modulo=1 eigenvalues, have infinite count of periodic points.

Also there is an evident application to Poincaré–Hopf theorem about sum of zero orders of vector field. Is there something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very nice proof of the existence of a maximal torus in a compact Lie group involving Lefschetz fixed point theorem, given in the third chapter of "J.F.Adams, *Lectures on Lie groups*, 1983".